# Cocos2d-x convertToNodeSpace anchorpoint

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Hi i'm having an issue with the convertToNodeSpace methode.
When I set the anchor point of the sprites to 0.5, 0.5 the convertToNodeSpace doesn't work right.

Example anchor-point 0,0 and 1,1 which works

```
Sprite *sprite1 = Sprite::create("CloseNormal.png");
sprite1->setPosition(Vec2(20,40));
sprite1->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0,0));
this->addChild(sprite1);

Sprite *sprite2 = Sprite::create("CloseNormal.png");
sprite2->setPosition(Vec2(5,-20));
sprite2->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(1,1));
this->addChild(sprite2);

Vec2 point1 = sprite1->convertToNodeSpace(sprite2->getPosition());
```

the output is position = (-15.000000,-60.000000) as expected
but when I change both anchor-points to 0.5 I get the following output

```
Sprite *sprite1 = Sprite::create("CloseNormal.png");
sprite1->setPosition(Vec2(20,40));
sprite1->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0.5,0.5));
this->addChild(sprite1);

Sprite *sprite2 = Sprite::create("CloseNormal.png");
sprite2->setPosition(Vec2(5,-20));
sprite2->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0.5,0.5));
this->addChild(sprite2);
```

the output position = (-5.625001,-50.625000)

When you add a sprite to a node the 0.5 0.5 anchor-point is used for setting the position. Maybe I'm missing something? this output seems weird to me

Comment: Please provide "CloseNormal.png" texture size

Comment: the convertToNodeSpace was the solution